# Train Videoindexer keyword extraction

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-media-services

Videoindexer was not picking up the expected keywords. Is there a way to train videoindexer to extract specific keywords?

Answer (score 0):

This customization functionality is not yet available unfortunately. Would be great if you could add this request to our user voice at https://aka.ms/vi-feedback. 
You can however update the keywords of a specific video by removing and adding keywords to it via the portal.